# How do I ignore N/A values in this SUM? (Google Sheets)

Tags: function, if-statement, google-sheets, sum

I do not know how to implement the IFNA function to my formula. Could you please help? I am using Google Sheets.

```
=SUM($G7+$I7+$K7+$M7+$U7+$W7+$AB7+$AE7)
```

Comment: `=SUMIF($G7+$I7+$K7+$M7+$U7+$W7+$AB7+$AE7,"<>#N/A")`

Comment: [Relevant Link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121407/294001)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Doesn't work, it says "Error: Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But 'N/A' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

Comment: Why those particular columns?  if there's a good reason they are the one's being added up, it will make the formula easier to write for you...

Comment: It's because of the visual and order of process of the table, there are other columns of information with different purposes

Comment: anything about the 'header' row in those columns that makes them easy to identify?  Looks like every other, but only in chunks.

Comment: Oops, wrong formatting. One way that'd work is: `=SUM(IFNA($G7, 0),IFNA($I7,0),IFNA($K7,0),IFNA($M7,0),IFNA($U7,0),IFNA($W7,0),IFNA($AB7,0),IFNA($AE7,0))`, though that's certainly not pretty.

Comment: Thanks, just realised the N/A value was actually #VALUE! so does that change anything?

Comment: Found it: =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR({$G7,$I7,$K7,$M7,$U7,$W7,$AB7,$AE7}))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array with the values and apply IFNA to each one before calculating the sum:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFNA({$G7,$I7,$K7,$M7,$U7,$W7,$AB7,$AE7}))
```

Note that SUMPRODUCT() works like SUM(ArrayFormula()

Comment: What about if it's "#VALUE!" in the equation?

Comment: You'll want to use `IFERROR(` instead of `IFNA(` if there are more than one type of error.

Comment: Then the result would be #VALUE! to indicate that something went wrong, since you only expect numbers or N/A, right? But if you want to ignore all errors, use IFERROR() instead of IFNA()

Comment: Found it: =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR({$G7,$I7,$K7,$M7,$U7,$W7,$AB7,$AE7}))

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem and I tried the answer similar to the one
BeRT2me responded in comment but with some changes:

1. Used range criteria instead of specific cells addition,
2. Repeat the same range after the criteria as sum_range as it says if criteria is text you need to give a range to add where it skips the cells that  matches the criteria.

=sumif(I68:I72,"<>#N/A",I68:I72)

Answer (score 1):

If this is not critical to you, it's easier to place IFNA directly into cell that could contain N/A and replace it with "" or 0.

```
=IFNA(FORMULA_THAT_CAN_RETURN_NA(), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `+` signs when using a formula like `SUM` or `SUMIF`.

For example, the same as your `SUM` formula above would be:

```
=SUM($G7,$I7,$K7,$M7,$U7,$W7,$AB7,$AE7)
```

One way to handle your error would be to wrap each item in `IFERROR` formulas:

```
=SUM(iferror($G7,0),iferror($I7,0),iferror($K7,0),etc...)
```

So for each one, it will show `0` instead of an error.

`SUMIF` is more helpful if you are summing up an entire row or column, with specific filtering criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Only some of the values contain N/A, so I'm meant to be getting a result that is more than zero as I'm totaling a point system. I tried this and all of my results give zero. This is what I have now: =SUM(iferror($G7,0),iferror($I7,0),iferror($K7,0),iferror($M7,0),iferror($U7,0),iferror($W7,0),iferror($AB7,0),iferror($AE7,0))

Comment: Found it: =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR({$G7,$I7,$K7,$M7,$U7,$W7,$AB7,$AE7}))